# How to control the position of a line accurately?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw a line and a half circle. I want them to have the same bottom, but they cannot have the same bottom line.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\tikz {
\draw[line width=2cm,red] (0,0) arc [radius=5,start angle=0, end angle=180];
\draw[line width=2cm,green] (0,0) arc [radius=5,start angle=0, end angle=-180];
\draw [line width=2cm, red] (-10,1) --  (0,1);
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: could you give a handrawn sketch of the desired output

Comment: thank you for your asking. I just want to know how to calculate the line width and coordinate . I think the half of the line width(=1cm) same the (-10,1) (0,1) y=1.

Comment: What you are seeing is a viewer artefact. Try a different viewer. If you really want, you could fill a complete half circle red, and then a white arc on top of that.

Comment: You are right. I open it in the photoshop, they have the same bottom line, but not in the adobe acrobat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid viewer artefacts and the thick line width, you can just layer appropriate shapes like this:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[green] (0,0) circle[radius=6];
\fill[white] (0,0) circle[radius=4];
\fill[red] (6,0) arc [radius=6, start angle=0, end angle=180] -- cycle;
\fill[white] ({asin(2/4)}:4) arc [radius=4, start angle=asin(2/4), end angle=180-asin(2/4)] -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Red green circle symbol]

If you need transparent background, here is the same thing using `even odd rule`:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[green, even odd rule] (0,0) circle[radius=6] (0,0) circle[radius=4];
\fill[red, even odd rule] (6,0) arc [radius=6, start angle=0, end angle=180] -- cycle ({asin(2/4)}:4) arc [radius=4, start angle=asin(2/4), end angle=180-asin(2/4)] -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thans for your answer.

Comment: could you explain the difference between asin(2/4) and angle 30, and the meaning of ({asin(2/4)}:4),  and how you get the value asin(2/4), Thanks@hpekristiansen

Comment: I prefer to let LaTeX do the calculation instead of me. `asin(2/4)` is the angle at 2 up and radius 4.

Comment: thanks a lot, I see